# LINQ select row with the minimum date value

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

i have this linq query:

```
    var query = from mpItem in MPay
                where mpItem.EndDate > System.DateTime.Now.Date
                group mpItem by mpItem.IdGroup into mpItemGrouped
                let minEndDate = mpItemGrouped.Min(p => p.EndDate)
                select new
                {
                    Id = mpItemGrouped.Key,
                    EndDate = mpItemGrouped.Min(p => p.EndDate),
                    Name = mpItemGrouped.Min(p => p.IdGroupModel.GroupName),
                    Price = mpItemGrouped.Min(p => p.PaySumIndividual)
                };
```

this query should select for each **IdGroup** the row with the minimum **EndDate**
this query is selecting the minimum **EndDate** with another row values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order group by `EndDate` in ascending order and select first item from group - that will be item with min date. Then use this item in select statement

```
   var query = from MPayItem in MPay
                where mpItem.EndDate > System.DateTime.Now.Date
                group mpItem by mpItem.IdGroup into mpItemGrouped
                let minItem = mpItemGrouped.OrderBy(p => p.EndDate).First()
                select new
                {
                    Id = mpItemGrouped.Key,
                    EndDate = minItem.EndDate,
                    Name = minItem.IdGroupModel.GroupName,
                    Price = minItem.PaySumIndividual
                };
```

Comment: this is working thanks, easy fix a mistake because my question: "MPayItem" should be "mpItem" in the first row. thank you very much.